# replace any string within quotes

Tags: c#

I have a string:

```
"Id=1,UserId=1,2,3,Name=Harry,Sam,Rena,Bob,Age=22"
```

I want to replace"," with ";" in the following spots :

```
"Id=1;UserId=1,2,3;Name=Harry,Sam,Rena,Bob;Age=22"
```

can someone please help?

Comment: Hey unhappy_vapor, what have you tried so far? Please be sure to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look for comma and following not comma characters and equal. Then replace with colon.

```js
var string = "Id=1,UserId=1,2,3,Name=Harry,Sam,Rena,Bob,Age=22",
    result = string.replace(/,(?=[^,]+=)/g, ';');

console.log(string);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: can you please do it in c#? string.replace does not wirking in c# @Nina Scholz

Comment: sorry, i have no idea of c#. the question is tagged with javascript.

Comment: @unhappy_vapor `Regex.Replace(string, ",(?=[^,]+=)", ";");`